How accurate is the Molecular Orbital Theory
When you take it to its core, when forming a covalent bond, which is more accurate, the MO theory with idea of electron behaving as waves and superimposition, and idea of forming Molecular orbitals and idea of delocalized framework from MO spanning the entire molecule or Valence Bond Theory with atomic orbital overlap where electron density is generally greatest at overlap and electrons are localized. I know both have flaws and I understand aren't able to perfectly describe molecules - such as in molecular geometry or reactivity or paramagentism.

Both those theories are equivalent (when taken to their respective limits).

VB theory does give some odd results and does not predict some properties related to spin coordinates. Also, there are cool experimental demonstrations of the validity of MO, the existence of molecular orbitals has been demonstrated.

@Martin Both theories use different theory - for example in electron localization and Molecular orbital theory states that Molecular orbitals are produced. There should be one that most accurately describes what is analyzed/ eperimentally observed when bonds formed

@user155568 you are fundamentally mistaken. Both formulations are equivalent as Martin mentioned. There is also a more modern and sophisticated version of the VB approach (GVB).  Without entering into details you can find this information in many introductions to Physical Chemistry or Quantum Chemistry textbooks. I can not recommend an specific one now but I think it was discussed in an article of the Journal of Chemical Education.

@PAEP If both are fundamentally equal, how and why are there two theories that state and utlize different things

@ChemLover68 you may find this article useful: Valence Bond and Molecular Orbital: Two Powerful Theories that Nicely Complement One Another, J. Chem. Educ. 2021, 98, 12, 3617–3620. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jchemed.1c00919. The article is available in open access.

@PAEP I think i get it - does VBT basically show it trough taking average of ground, non-ground covalent state and ionic states. So hydrogen main contributor is ground covalent state and this also gives partial delocalization like in MO theory (But this is only for modern Coulson fischer VB with quantum chemistry). However it does give me 2 questions - What would differ to make it show more delocalization (example in benzene or ozone compared to hydrogen as base VBT would show it through resonance or equal bonds.

@PAEP and also for oxygen, would main contributor be triplet state as that is it's ground state. But then how would it show paramagnetism this way. Also i got all this through wikipedia (Modern VBT) and article on how Quantum chemistry affects VBT (E.g Methods like Coulson Fischer method)

It might relate to General Valence Bond Theory but I can't understand. All I undertsand is that unlike normal VBT, Modern VBT uses wavefunctions and a mixture of different structures. I see coulson fischer method which I said is related to general valence bond theory

@ChemLover68 You may find useful this question What is actually the difference between valence bond theory and molecular orbital theory?.

I am not sure what is your starting point. You would have a better perspective of the model and its limitations if you consult an introduction to ab initio methods in Quantum Chemistry and something on the Natural Bond Orbitals/Localized Orbitals though this may be too advanced at this stage.
